# VBA Find Method not returning value that does in fact exist in sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to be able to find values in a worksheet.  I am successfully matching string values on the first two iterations in the loop.  The third iteration causes an error on the line immediately below.  The error is of the type

> "object variable or with block variable not set".

The string value in the find method is correct (when I hover my mouse over it), but the range variable does not record anything (it reads nothing).  I am fairly certain the properties associated with the find method are correct.

Also, I attempted to search the string "08/17/2015" in the sheet and also was not able to successfully match it despite observing its presence. I tried the several combinations offered in the find tool box, but nothing seemed to work.  Any ideas why this is failing on this date value now?  Ideas on how to further troubleshoot this?

```
.Range(sampleSet, sampleSet.End(xlToRight)).Copy

For aa = 1 To samples

sampleVar = wkbk.Sheets("AllDistanceMeasures").Cells(aa + 4, 11).value

With Workbooks(COMBINED).Worksheets(Contract)

Set sampleSet = .Cells.Find(What:=sampleVar, After:=.Range("A1"), 
LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

.Range(sampleSet, sampleSet.End(xlToRight)).Copy

End With

Workbooks("KMEANS_TEMPLATE.xls").Sheets("Destination").Cells(aa + 8, 
4).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Next aa
```

Comment: Do the date formats match? What's the value (and data type) of `sampleVar`?

Comment: Are you ending the With statement after your first line of code there? You are calling .Range like it's in a With statement, but then you don't end it and start another one, is that intentional?

Comment: Finding **Dates** in cells in VBA can be confusing. Unless the cells are stored as "Text", searching `"08/17/2015"` will get you Nothing. Searching dates stored as values need conversion. ie `sampleVar = CDate(wkbk.Sheets("AllDistanceMeasures").Cells(aa + 4, 11).value)`

Comment: Comintern Yes, the date formats match. The value giving the error is "03/29/2011" and sampleVar is a string.

blaasd I don't follow you. I only see a single with statement with two parts the Set range part and the range that is copied. what do you mean?

patrick I changed the string variable assignments to include CDate, but am still receiving an object variable or with block variable not set error.

Comment: blaasd  correction.  Yes the first line of code is followed by an end with statement.  The first line is the line producing the error